# Are there any High Level, easy to install GUI libraries for Common Lisp?

Tags: user-interface, lisp, common-lisp

Are there any good, cross platform (SBCL and CLISP at the very least) easy to install GUI libraries?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Ltk](http://www.peter-herth.de/ltk/) is quite popular, very portable, and reasonably well documented through the Tk docs.  Installation on SBCL is as easy as saying:

```
(require :asdf-install)
(asdf-install:install :ltk)
```

There's also [Cells-Gtk](http://common-lisp.net/project/cells-gtk/), which is reported to be quite usable but may have a slightly steeper learning curve because of its reliance on Cells.

EDIT: Note that ASDF-INSTALL is integrated this well with SBCL *only*.  Installing libraries from within other Lisp implementations may prove harder.  (Personally, I always install my libraries from within SBCL and then use them from all implementations.)  Sorry about any confusion this may have caused.

Comment: It turned out to not really be a problem, just had to manually compile and load LTK, and then made me a new image, from then onwards its all gone smoothly. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: I've found the documentation a little sparse myself, but I've run ltk.lisp through Albert and the output looks promising.

Answer (score 7):

[clg](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clg) is a binding of GTK for Common Lisp. Both complete and lispish.

If you want to design graphical interfaces in CL, you might want to take a look at CLIM, too, which some kind of standard API for GUIs. Allegro and Lispworks have their own implementation of it, and there's a free software one, [McCLIM](http://common-lisp.net/project/mcclim/).

Answer (score 5):

Also, just found a Smoke library QT bindings, called [CommonQt](http://common-lisp.net/project/commonqt/) for CL

Answer (score 2):

There's also [wxCL](http://www.wxcl-project.org/), providing CFFI bindings for [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/).

Comment: That project seems to be dead. The last upload to the sourceforge site was in 2006, and wxcl homepage has apparently been hacked and word-filtered.

Comment: 4 years later it looks like the project and site are just fine, and the project's getting lots of commits (https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/commits/master)

Comment: I don't see any Common Lisp bindings in the link you provided, and the www.wxcl-project.org site now points to some Japanese blog.

Comment: Yeah, I meant to recall my comment - where I pointed to wxWidgets, not the CL bindings - and then it looked like SO didn't even add the comment, and here we are :/

Answer (score 2):

LispWorks comes with CAPI, it's portable accross Mac, Windows and Linux and even has some GUI-Builder. It's free for personal use.