# How do I use (require :PACKAGE) in clisp under Ubuntu Hardy?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lisp, common-lisp, asdf

I am trying to evaluate the answer [provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108081/are-there-any-high-level-easy-to-install-gui-libraries-for-common-lisp), and am getting the error: `"A file with name ASDF-INSTALL does not exist"` when using clisp:

```
dsm@localhost:~$ clisp -q
[1]> (require :asdf-install)

*** - LOAD: A file with name ASDF-INSTALL does not exist
The following restarts are available:
ABORT          :R1      ABORT
Break 1 [2]> :r1
[3]> (quit)

dsm@localhost:~$
```

cmucl throws a similar error:

```
dsm@localhost:~$ cmucl -q
Warning:  #<Command Line Switch "q"> is an illegal switch
CMU Common Lisp CVS release-19a 19a-release-20040728 + minimal debian patches, running on crap-pile
With core: /usr/lib/cmucl/lisp.core
Dumped on: Sat, 2008-09-20 20:11:54+02:00 on localhost
For support see http://www.cons.org/cmucl/support.html Send bug reports to the debian BTS.
or to pvaneynd@debian.org
type (help) for help, (quit) to exit, and (demo) to see the demos

Loaded subsystems:
    Python 1.1, target Intel x86
    CLOS based on Gerd's PCL 2004/04/14 03:32:47
* (require :asdf-install)


Error in function REQUIRE:  Don't know how to load ASDF-INSTALL
   [Condition of type SIMPLE-ERROR]

Restarts:
  0: [ABORT] Return to Top-Level.

Debug  (type H for help)

(REQUIRE :ASDF-INSTALL NIL)
Source: 
; File: target:code/module.lisp
(ERROR "Don't know how to load ~A" MODULE-NAME)
0] (quit)
dsm@localhost:~$
```

But sbcl works perfectly:

```
dsm@localhost:~$ sbcl -q
This is SBCL 1.0.11.debian, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.

SBCL is free software, provided as is, with absolutely no warranty.
It is mostly in the public domain; some portions are provided under
BSD-style licenses.  See the CREDITS and COPYING files in the
distribution for more information.
* (require :asdf-install)

; loading system definition from
; /usr/lib/sbcl/sb-bsd-sockets/sb-bsd-sockets.asd into #<PACKAGE "ASDF0">
; registering #<SYSTEM SB-BSD-SOCKETS {AB01A89}> as SB-BSD-SOCKETS
; registering #<SYSTEM SB-BSD-SOCKETS-TESTS {AC67181}> as SB-BSD-SOCKETS-TESTS
("SB-BSD-SOCKETS" "ASDF-INSTALL")
* (quit)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? I found [this post](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/common-lisp-controller/+bug/37208) on the internet, but using that didn't work either.

Comment: Yes, sorry.  I probably should have explicitely mentioned that it's that easy with SBCL only, but I don't know of any other way of installing any Lisp library easily.  I'm going to have to have a look at clbuild sometime.

Comment: (Personally, I always install everything through SBCL and use it from all Lisp implementations afterwards.  All of my Lisp compilers use the same ASDF system registry.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use clc:clc-require in clisp. Refer to 'man common-lisp-controller'. I had the same error in clisp and resolved it by using clc:clc-require. sbcl works fine with just require though.

Answer (score 3):

try this before anything else:

```
(require :asdf)
```

you can steal some ideas from the environment we use. it's available at: [darcsweb](http://dwim.hu/darcsweb/darcsweb.cgi?r=HEAD%20hu.dwim.environment;a=summary)

see environment.lisp that loads and sets up asdf for us. (sbcl has asdf already loaded)

Answer (score 3):

The instructions you got mentioned SBCL explicitely, so it's expected that they'll work better using SBCL, I suppose. Some other Lisps don't come with ASDF or don't hook it up to CL:REQUIRE. In the former case, you'll have load ASDF yourself beforehand. In the latter case, you'll need to call (asdf:oos 'asdf:load-op ) instead of (require ).

Answer (score 3):

wget http://cclan.cvs.sourceforge.net/*checkout*/cclan/asdf/asdf.lisp

It worth checking out clbuild.  http://common-lisp.net/project/clbuild/

To get a lisp webserver up and running. You only need:

```
darcs get http://common-lisp.net/project/clbuild/clbuild
cd clbuild
chmod +x ./clbuild
./clbuild check
./clbuild build slime hunchentoot
./clbuild preloaded
```

Now a lisp repl will start. There you write:

```
* (hunchentoot:start-server :port 8080)
```

Testing that the server answer:

```
wget -O - http://localhost:8080/

<html><head><title>Hunchentoot</title></head>
 <body><h2>Hunchentoot Default Page</h2>
  <p>This is the Hunchentoot default page....
```